# Gap Under Drop-down Menu

Tags: css, html, dropdown

I have a drop-down menu on a site that I have been working on I and I need to get rid of this gap above the drop-down menu. It is quite bothersome.

[Figure A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbfGv.jpg)

So, in an attempt to fix it, I changed the li line-height from 50px to 47px and got this:

[Figure B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPRLx.png)

Almost what I want, but not quite. The problem? The li is higher causing the little animation I have under the li to no longer touch the image.

Then, I tried giving the li a relative position. But now, the drop-down is the same width as the 'Patient Info' link.

[Figure C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNFow.jpg)

Here is my [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rgtow2p5/11/) if you would like to fiddle around with it. There is no rush. Thank you!

Code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  max-width: 2500px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro');
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

img#profile {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 64px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.header,
.menu,
.hero,
.slider,
.img-display {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #11b5e4;
  color: white;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #11b5e4;
  color: white;
}

/* HEADER & MENU STYLE START */

.header {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
}

.header img {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.header a i {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
  color: black;
  transition: .15s color;
}

.header a i:hover {
  color: #11b5e4;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.5, 3, .5, .5) background;
  color: black;
  background: linear-gradient(#11b5e4, #11b5e4) 50% 100%/100% 0px no-repeat;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#11b5e4, #11b5e4) 50% 100%/100% 5px no-repeat;
}

.menu-wrapper #toggle-menu {
  display: none;
}

/* FOR STACK OVERFLOW */

.menu li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  background: white;
}


ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
}

/* END OF FOR STACK OVERFLOW */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .menu {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    transition: .25s opacity;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .menu-wrapper #toggle-menu:checked~.menu {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .menu li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px 15px;
  }
  .menu-wrapper label {
    align-self: center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .menu-wrapper label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu-wrapper label#open-menu {
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .3s;
    background: url(http://ianspence.us/stack/menu-open-icon.png) center center/cover no-repeat;
  }
  .menu-wrapper label#close-menu {
    transition: opacity .5s, transform .3s;
    background: url(http://ianspence.us/stack/menu-close-icon.png) center center/cover no-repeat;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .menu-wrapper #toggle-menu:checked~label#open-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  .menu-wrapper #toggle-menu:checked~label#close-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .header {
    height: 75px;
  }
  .header h1 {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .header a i {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  }
}

/* HEADER & MENU STYLE END */

/* HERO START */

.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(150px + 20vw);
  width: 100%;
}

.hero h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: rgba(17, 181, 228, .75);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.hero.a {
  align-items: flex-end;
  background: url(http://ianspence.us/stack/hero.a.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
}

.hero.b {
  align-items: flex-end;
  background: url(media/hero.b.jpeg) center/cover no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .hero.a,
  .hero.b {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .hero.a h1,
  .hero.b h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero.a,
  .hero.b {
    height: 250px;
  }
  .hero.a h1,
  .hero.b h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

/* HERO END */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>@pfcainc | Home</title>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='http://ianspence.us/stack/icon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='media/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css'>
    <meta name='description' content=''>
    <meta name='keywords' content=''>
    <meta name='robots' content='index, follow'>
    <meta name='revisit-after' content='3 days'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1'>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='header'>
      <img src='http://ianspence.us/stack/icon.png'>
      <h1>Panhandle Family Care Associates</h1>
      <a href='https://facebook.com/panhandlefamilycareassociates/'><i class='fab fa-facebook-square'></i></a>
      <a href='https://twitter.com/pfcainc'><i class='fab fa-twitter'></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-wrapper'>
      <input type='checkbox' id='toggle-menu'>
      <label for='toggle-menu' id='open-menu'></label>
      <label for='toggle-menu' id='close-menu'></label>
      <!--Start Menu Display-->
      <div class='menu'>
        <li><a href='=./'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='services'>Services</a></li>
        <li><a href='physicians'>Physicians</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Patient Info</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='patient-forms'>Patient Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href='patient-education'>Patient Education</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://myhealthrecord.com'>Patient Portal</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='office-info'>Office Info</a></li>
      </div>
      <!--End Menu Display-->
    </div>
    <div class='hero a'>
      <h1>Treating your family like ours since 2002</h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Notes:

- In jsfiddle, make sure you increase the width of the preview so that the
  full menu is there, not the hamburger menu.
- I am trying to avoid Javascript completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-top: -3px` for submenu seems to fix the issue across all (major) browsers, however I'd recommend fix from my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/ERdyNe), with flex and defined height for `li` elements.

#### Fast & simple

HTML:

```
<ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href='patient-forms'>Patient Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href='patient-education'>Patient Education</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://myhealthrecord.com'>Patient Portal</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.submenu {
  margin-top: -3px !important;
}
```

#### More clean approach

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/ERdyNe)

Comment: Hmm... That was pretty simple. 

Comment: I edited my answer. I'd recommend you using fixed height for `li` elements instead of `line-height` and using flex for it's `a` content. See my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/ERdyNe).

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help and don't hesitate to ask again.